# Как спарсить ссылки?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = 'https://stopgame.ru/news'
HEADERS = {'ll'}

def get_html(url, params=None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers = HEADERS, params = params )       #float == 0.1, int == 0
    return r

def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    for x in soup.select('.article-summary .caption'):
        print(x.get_text(strip=True)

def parse():
    html = get_html(URL)
    print (html)
    get_content (html.text)

parse()
```

Как можно спарсить href ссылки?

Я пробовал через `soup.find_all` с указанием тега и с указанием класса, но не получается...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Через soup.find_all с указанием тега и с указанием класса

Если правильно указать теги и классы:

```py
def stop_game():
    url = 'https://stopgame.ru/news'

    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

    articles = soup.find_all('div', class_='caption caption-bold')
    for a in articles:
        print(a.find('a')['href'])
```

и выведет:

```
/newsdata/46231
/newsdata/46230
/newsdata/46229

...

/newsdata/46213
/newsdata/46212
/newsdata/46211
```